# Why should I move to Selenium 2 from Selenium 1?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

What are the real benefits of using Selenium 2 instead of Selenium 1? I've read several posts related to new version but didn't get what are the advantages of Selenium 2.

Comment: Please check related question in stack overflow [Selenium 1 to Selenium 2 Migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692173/selenium-1-to-selenium-2-migration). I would suggest you to evaulate pros/cons based on this analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the short answer is, you shouldn't. There basically only 2 reasons for moving to the newer version:

1. The older version has some critical problems that you always have to solve with dirty hacks and workarounds. If the newer version is known to have these issues fixed, there's a reason to  upgrade.
2. The older version is not supported anymore. That's not applicable to Selenium, since it's toooo open source (read as - "noone cares if it doesn't work").

So, the best approach here is spending some efforts on checking what the newer version does and how it does it.